# List index is out of range when passing empty values

Tags: python, html, json, list, flask

Okay so I have the following HTML form:

```
<form method ="post" action="/custom">

  <div class="container">
   <select multiple name ="multiple">
  <option value="id">ID</option>
  <option value="is_visible">Visible</option>
</select>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>

</div>
</form>
```

And I have the following Python code to insert values in to the database

```
@app.route('/custom',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def custom_fields():
    login = 'urlhere.com'
    url_tags = 'targeturlhere.com/page.json'
    multiple = request.form.getlist('multiple')
    post = session.post(login, data=payload)
    r_tags = session.get(url_tags)
    parsed_tags = json.loads(r_tags.text)


    for tag in parsed_tags['tags']:

            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.tags"
                           "(tagid, is_visible, products_count, slug, title, created_at ,updated_at )"
                           "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" 
                           ,(tag[multiple[0]],tag[multiple[1]], tag['products_count']
                           ,tag['slug'],tag['title'],tag['created_at'],tag['updated_at']))
            con.commit()
```

So what I do now is to select the values that I want to pass to the Python code. My problem now is that if I choose the values that the code is working, but if I don't choose something I get the following:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there any possible way to pass empty values and to accomplish what I want?  Also note that I am working with json code, see a format below:

```
{
tags: [
{
created_at: "2018-02-28T14:55:19+01:00",
customer_id: null,
id: 4544544,
is_visible: true,
products_count: 6,
slug: "productname",
title: "productname",
updated_at: "2018-05-25T00:08:04+02:00"
},
],
}
```

Comment: just check the length of list is zero. len(list) != 0. if it is not zero do your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are passing an empty value for the `multiple` key. The simplest solution would be to check the contents of the `multiple` list right after taking it from the request. If it is empty, use a default one:

```
multiple = request.form.getlist('multiple')
if not multiple or len(multiple) < 2:
    multiple = ['default_tag', 'default_is_visible']
```

Comment: If I try that I will get a key_error cause the tag I replace it with doesn't exist in the JSON table. So I have to look for another solution.